# unable to cast to personal whitelisted receiver app

Tags: android, google-cast

I have successfully used the Android TicTacToe app to cast to the TicTacToe receiver app (AppID "TicTacToe"), using unmodified code from the [TicTacToe example on github](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-tictactoe/).

Next, I tried to use my personal receiver app. I got the email a couple of hours letting me know that my device was whitelisted and providing the AppID. I put the AppID in line 90 on GameActivity.java (not line 91, as stated in the instructions), and I also put it in line 35 of tictactoe.html (this step was missing from the instructions, but I assume it is needed). I also followed all steps in the Common Errors section of the instructions.

When I click the Start button in the Android app, the Tic-Tac-Toe board appears in the Android app, but the Chromecast device does not noticeably react.

Here is the LogCat:

```
07-28 00:13:47.776: W/StartSessionTask(10892): StartApplicationRequest failed with status: -4
07-28 00:13:47.826: E/ApplicationSession(10892): StartSessionTask failed with error: failed to start application: request failed
07-28 00:13:47.826: D/GameActivity(10892): start session failed: failed to start application: request failed
```

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952997/setting-up-android-cast-sdk will solve your issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try checking the box that says "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates".

Mine didn't work at first, after doing this and restarting mine seemed to pick up the whitelisted appID.

As mentioned by the author of question: Make sure to do from ChromeOS, Windows or Mac OSX client until they fix the issue from Android app.

Clients can be downloaded here: https://cast.google.com/chromecast/setup

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't get that setting to stick. After checking it, pressing up, then returning to the Chromecast's settings, it again appears unchecked. (I'm using the Android Chromecast app.)

Comment: As mentioned in other google-cast questions, the Android app has a bug where this setting doesn't stick. I used the Windows Chromecast app to apply the setting instead, then rebooted the Chromecast, and it is now working.

Comment: I had noticed it didn't stick but thought I was doing something wrong.  Good to know!  Updated the answer with that additional information.

Comment: I had to search a lot for the windows desktop application link... so here [it is](https://cast.google.com/chromecast/setup)

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed for me after I restarted the chromecast by removing power.

Comment: Just removing power and then restarting did not fix the issue for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17913844/445348) several times (was finally able to get the setting to stick using the Chromecast Mac app) but it still was giving this same error.

Then, I discovered I actually uploaded the receiver file to the wrong url. So double check which url was actually whitelisted!

Though even after fixing the url it still was broken. So I think I must have entered the wrong serial number when I made the whitelist request. I resent the whitelist request and the new app ids are working properly.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I double/triple checked mine, as I was afraid I would type it wrong.  Wasn't sure how many times they would let you request device whitelisting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem by using HTTP  instead of HTTPS for my local hosted receiver, it seems Chromecast looks for valid certificate.