# Chromecast "StartApplicationRequest failed with status: -4"

Tags: google-cast

I've set up the Chromecast SDK, whitelisted my device, and am running web servers at the URLs I provided in the whitelist request.

***The chromecast tic tac toe app works fine with the default app id "TicTacToe"***, however changing it to my own: "1813060e-33c5-41dc-b356-0d2bad12497f" or "1813060e-33c5-41dc-b356-0d2bad12497f_1" does not work.

The server url is up and running at http://chromecast.clockworkmod.com/, but no requests are being made to it by Chromecast. The chromecast doesn't display anything. However I get a few errors in the log.

Here is the logcat.

> W/StartSessionTask(15590): StartApplicationRequest failed with status:
>   -4 E/ApplicationSession(15590): StartSessionTask failed with error: failed to start application: request failed D/GameActivity(15590):
>   start session failed: failed to start application: request failed

I've also tried using the internal app id with the dev url I had provided, `http://192.168.1.2:3000/`

Comment: That seems odd. As soon as I get mine in the mail I'll be trying basically the same thing. I'll see if I run into the same issue. You could try using wireshark to see if any request is attempted at all(Even towards the wrong URL). Unless you know this is an application problem. You are sure the format of your APP ID is good?

Comment: I'm copy and pasting the app id straight from the email they sent me.

Comment: This may seem like a lot of work for possibly nothing but you could check with wireshark to see if it's contacting the website correctly and all. Of course you will have to set up your network the right way to make it possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[unable to cast to personal whitelisted receiver app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905985/unable-to-cast-to-personal-whitelisted-receiver-app)

Using the Chromecast app on my Macbook, I went into Settings.

- Send serial number when Checking for updates
- Reboot device the device using the Mac update app

This resolved the error for me. The chromecast doesn't know if it is whitelisted unless you send the serial during update checks.

Comment: Attempted to answer this last week and ended up using your answer myself!

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's missing! In your receiver you gave a link to, you have:

```
var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(
    'GoogleCastSampleApp', 
    [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE],
    "",
    5);
```

But it should be (fill in the 'YOUR APP ID HERE' with your App ID)

```
var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(
    'YOUR APP ID HERE', 
    [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE],
    "",
    5);
```

Comment: I don't think so, the docs indicate that it is just an "activity name". https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/receiver/jsdoc/cast.receiver.Receiver

I tried changing it anyways, just to be sure, and it still did not work.

Comment: Given that the device is not making any requests to the url, I suspect that the whitelist process was botched.

Comment: @koush The guide said to put the App Id there, that's why I figured it would help(guess not). https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver

Comment: The help was still appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same error as well.  I after setting the Chromecast to send the serial when checking for updates I was finally able to access the debugger one port 9222.  Unfortunately, I don't see anything happen on the Chromecast at all when I select it from the device list on my Nexus and try sending one of the demo videos.

Something I noticed and I don't know it makes difference or not but if you whitelist a domain in the GoogleCast extension for Chrome and you include the "http://" it will cause the injection to not work.  I wonder if this is the problem with the look up that the Chromecast performs as I submitted my URLs to Google with the http:// prepended.  Again I am not sure this should really make a difference but I plan on trying to resubmit the URLs just to see.

Answer (score 0):

Install cURL in your windows machine from [here](http://download.cnet.com/cURL/3000-2065_4-54546.html)

Now make sure that your device and laptop are in same network.

Now go to command prompt, type **curl -d "" http://:8008/apps/YouTube**

there If it gets casted automatically to TV then instead of YouTube put your appid and try.

If not then your router is blocking some traffic.