# Chromecast app starting from sample TicTacToe - failed to start application: request failed

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I have a whitelisted URL for my Chromecast and I'm able to install and run the sample TicTacToe app using the code out of the box. But when I switch "TicTacToe" to my app id, I get this in LogCat:

```
StartApplicationRequest failed with status: -4
StartSessionTask failed with error: failed to start application: request failed
start session failed: failed to start application: request failed
```

I have looked through many SO questions where people failed to get their own App Id's working, but those solutions have not solved my issue. For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17916608/1399483 Also, Google emailed telling me they messed up the app id the first time, and so they sent me a new id. I am using it.

Changes I've made:

First, in GameActivity I changed

```
    try {
        mSession.startSession("TicTacToe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open a session", e);
    }
```

to

```
    try {
        mSession.startSession("<the new app id from Google>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open a session", e);
    }
```

Then in TicTacToe.html I changed

```
      var chromecastApp = new cast.receiver.Receiver("TicTacToe",
      [ cast.TicTacToe.PROTOCOL ], "", 5);
```

to

```
      var chromecastApp = new cast.receiver.Receiver("<the new app id from Google>",
      [ cast.TicTacToe.PROTOCOL ], "", 5);
```

So when starting from the sample code - including the sender and receiver - how many total changes need to be made, and in which files? Am I missing some? If not, then I'll go back to Google to see if something still got messed up.

Comment: I just left them both as TicTacToe and it worked fine

Comment: @schwiz that won't help much when you want to develop. If you leave it unchanged that means you are not hitting the web app at your own URL. Instead you are hitting some unknown to us URL that Google initially set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I typed in my serial number incorrectly. After an email to the guys at Google and a very quick reply(thanks Les), things are up and running.

So, **to answer the question for those who come after me**, the 2 changes I made and pointed out in my question are all it takes to get things working with your own app ID. If things aren't working with those changes, let Google know and they can look into whether you submitted your web form incorrectly, etc.

My 2 suggestions for Google:

1. Please make those serial numbers more easily readable
2. Maybe send an email to the developer when the web form is submitted so that she/he can double check what was submitted

Comment: Did you have to rename tictactoe.html on your server? How does it know how to look for tictactoe.html? Thanks.

Comment: @thought.tinkerer You need that file to be named as it is in your white listed URL. So I whitelisted myveryowndomain.com/cast/tictactoe.html but if I had white listed .../cast/foo then the file would need to be renamed to foo.

Answer (score -1):

In file README_ECLIPSE.txt it says:

```
In GameActivity at line 91, the code makes a call to the app name "TicTacToe". 
This is a whitelisted app name at which the TicTacToe receiver is located, 
so you can simply build and run the app without worrying about whitelisting 
your own receiver.
```

So please do not change anything in the sample code (to replace with your AppId), just build and run to see if it works for you.

If you can't make that work, please check the answer here:

[Unable to debug Whitelisted device / ApplicationSession failing to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911939/unable-to-debug-whitelisted-device-applicationsession-failing-to-start/17914127#17914127)

Comment: as I mentioned I can get all of the sample code to work "out of the box". As you've pointed out, anyone can. The question here is, what is the minimum number of changes to get it working with a white listed URL.