# Setting up android cast sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cast

I can't quite seem to get the cast SDK set up in eclipse.  I'm supposed to import the project, then add it to my application project.  I tried that, but I still can't access classes like CastContext.   Any tips?  I'm excited to get working on this thing!

Comment: I got it.  I had to make sure that the cast library was exporting it's jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Download the Android Support package with the SDK Manager. It should include mediarouter and appcompat.
- Should also download the actual cast api: https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastSdkAndroid-1.0.0.zip ... You can miss this link when reading the downloads page (at least that's what happened to me).
- Then import them all into Eclipse (File->Import), the support packages should be under sdk/extras/android/support/v7/mediarouter and sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat. The cast package is wherever you saved it (I just put it in the sdk/ directory).
- The mediarouter depends on the appcompat, so you want to add it to the mediarouter project as a library.
- Head over to your application project and add the newly created mediarouter, appcompat and GoogleCastSdkAndroid packages.

That should take care of it all for you.

Comment: The dependency you need is in $ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. Regardless of how you manage to get that into your classpath (or ide's classpath), that's what you need.

Comment: the cast API isn't just a single zip file anymore, and I get this error even with the new ones.